# css flexbox align header to the body

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I have a problem: I'm trying to make a table with flex and div but I have problem with the header and the body, the header are aligned wrong to the body.

This is my code - help me please. I do not need to use table; I want to use folex css and div to simulate the table visualization. I need this because I have problem with the html validator accessibility

```css
.css-flex-table {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.css-flex-table-header,
.css-flex-table-body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  align-content: left;
}

.css-flex-table,
.css-flex-table-body {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.css-flex-table-header {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #dfdfdf;
}

.css-flex-table-header div {
  font-family: 'Open Sans bold';
  color: #002e5f;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.css-flex-table-header div,
.css-flex-table-body div {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  padding: 5px 4px 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
}

.css-flex-table-body:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

.css-flex-table-body:hover {
  background: #e6e8f1;
}
```

```html
<div class="css-flex-table">
  <div class="css-flex-table-header">
    <div></div>
    <div>dataInizio</div>
    <div>dataFine</div>
    <div>datoreDiLavoro</div>
    <div>mansione</div>
    <div></div>
  </div>

  <div class="css-flex-table-body">
    <div>
      <input type="radio" />
    </div>
    <div>dd/MM/yyyy</div>
    <div>dd/MM/yyyy</div>
    <div>denominazioneDl</div>
    <div>descrizione</div>
    <div>propostaAttribuzioneRischio</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just use an actual table that's what they are for. Alternatively Css-grid might be a better option.

Comment: i can not use table i have problem with accessibility, ok you think css grid is beter?? can you show me a css grid example?